# how to call a function with parameter in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function written in node js

```
var update = function(problem,TicketNo){
  const axios = require('axios');

  axios.get('https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?ticket=TicketNo&problem=problem')
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response);
    // console.log(response.data.explanation);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}
exports.update = update;
```

I am exporting it to further use and calling it like this: `update(problem, TicketNo)`

But I am getting this error:  **ERROR: ChatConnector: error dispatching event(s) -**

When I call this function without parameters the call is successful.

What is the proper way to call a function with parameters in node js?

**I think there is an error in how I am calling the method**

Comment: You need to use template strings that allow embedded expressions with your variables i.e. change the line `axios.get('https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?ticket=TicketNo&problem=problem'')` to ```axios.get(`https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?ticket=${TicketNo}&problem=${problem}`)```

Comment: still getting same error..

Comment: Post the full error log please

Comment: @dubonzi i am getting only this in error log ERROR: ChatConnector: error dispatching event(s) -

Comment: Thats the full error? No stack trace? Seems like the error has nothing to do with the code you provided. Look at the stack trace and see where it happens

Comment: [Please read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You need to provide more information about the problem.

Comment: @dubonzi i am very new to node js and i did know how to get full error..this ie the error which i am getting in command prompt only

Comment: If you google the error, you'll see that it's not related to the nasa api or axios, but to the Microsoft Bot Framework, and the code you provided doesn't show anything about that.

Comment: @dubonzi okay.. thanks for suggestion. i will check other side also

Answer (score 1):

actually you have to errors on your axios call.

1. you are not using the parameters of your function.
2. you have 2 `'` at the end.

you should change this:

`axios.get('https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?ticket=TicketNo&problem=problem'')`

to this:

`` axios.get(`https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?ticket=${TicketNo}&problem=${problem}`) ``

Comment: i have changed my axios line to  ` axios.get(`https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?ticket=${TicketNo}&problem=${problem}`) `

Comment: i think i am not able to make call.because i am trying to print some statement before axios but it is also not printing

Comment: actually I fixed what you were trying to achieve on the title of the ticket, but looks the error is not related to this piece of code, because it seems perfect.
dont you have a stacktrace of the error?